# How to pass value to qweb odoo14

Tags: odoo, qweb

How can I pass value to qweb and add to binary field. Everything is fine but I don't know how to add value to qweb. Here is my code.

```html
def button_plan(self):
        super(MrpProduction, self).button_plan()
        for report in self.bom_id.reports:
            report_name = "action_report_template"
            template = report
            pdf = self.env.ref('my_module.action_report_template')._render_qweb_pdf(self.ids)
            report.operation_id.worksheet_type = 'pdf'
            report.operation_id.worksheet = base64.b64encode(pdf[0])
```

How can I add template value to qweb.

Answer (score 1):

The method _render_qweb_pdf  has 2 possible parameters ids and data

You can found more information here.
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py#L726